# memorable name generator gem for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Before I go roll my own and start pulling out the dictionary, does anyone know a rubygem to generate memorable names suitable for app keys.  I need something pronounceable so that I can give users unique email addresses to submit content to.  I like Heroku's naming for it's apps as an example.

```
floating-sky-58
simple-fog-45
```

Comment: Check that your dictionary doesn't contain any "bad words". Such a random generator can easily create something considered offensive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use randexp gem. It's use the dictionnary from your OS ( UNIX only )

with [randexp gem](https://github.com/benburkert/randexp) you can do something like :

```
/[:word:]-[:word:]-\d+/.gen
```

and have like heroku naming.

If your server has no dict library install you can try [faker](http://rubygems.org/gems/faker)  or [Lorem](http://lorem.rubyforge.org/)

but really much limitated.

Comment: well, almost perfect except heroku doesn't have the dictionary! works fine on my local machine though

Comment: You might want to watch out for rude words :)  I seem to remember a DailyWTF along these lines.

Answer (score 20):

I just did an implementation of this for a project and my solution was to use the Forgery gem and something like this:

```
[Forgery::Basic.color, Forgery::Address.street_name.split(" ").first, rand(100)].join("-").downcase
```

This results in strings like this:

```
=> "orange-nobel-93"
=> "indigo-holmberg-41"
=> "khaki-sunfield-31"
=> "goldenrod-warrior-92"
=> "fuscia-manley-75"
=> "violet-village-17"
=> "violet-west-11"
=> "goldenrod-oak-74"
=> "yellow-hermina-74"
=> "red-shopko-36"
=> "purple-esch-43"
=> "teal-sutherland-44"
=> "blue-butterfield-56"
=> "yellow-mcbride-41"
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at my gem, does exactly this

gem 'bazaar'

```
Bazaar.heroku
=> "inquisitive-cavern-6617"
=> "jubilant-sunset-9301"
=> "frightened-geyser-4542"
```

https://rubygems.org/gems/bazaar

Comment: And faster than memorable_password by a TON. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [haikunator](https://github.com/usmanbashir/haikunator) gem is a good choice.