# Generating simple passwords based on dictionary words in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dictionary, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passwords, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there an easy way to generate simple passwords in Rails? I'd like to just grab 2 random dictionary words like AOL used to do a long time ago (I know that isn't very secure, they don't need to be very secure for my purposes).

Comment: How about using forgery gem like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7516358/1081340

Comment: @Slartibartfast - interesting, I had seen the forgery gem, but hadn't thought to use it like that. Just add a color and a street name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on my comment - Use the forgery gem like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7516358/1081340 but modified like so (a colour and a streetname or any combination you want)

```
[Forgery::Basic.color, Forgery::Address.street_name.split(" ").first].join("").downcase
```

which gives you passwords like

```
=>  orangenobel
=>  fusciamanley
=>  violetvillage
```

The advantage is you have control on two names and dont have to worry about a random dictionary generator generating passwords like `spitface` or `headache` (or something NSFW :), not a good problem to have) and it gives a nice heroku url feel to it.
For random dictionary words - use http://rubygems.org/gems/random-word or https://github.com/benburkert/randexp to generate two words and then attach to each other. But then you might have to filter out bad seeds :)

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following to generate a random password based on dictionary words.**

password = "#{DICTIONARY.rand}"
to generate a random password from a dictionary word.

***To make it more complex concatenate a random number with it.***

password = "#{DICTIONARY.rand}#{rand(20) + 1}"